# Move all subfolders of all folders in "Input" to "Output"

Tags: windows, batch-file, move, directory

I want to write a batch file that will move the subfolders of each folder in "Input" to "Output" which is in the same folder. Should two subfolders have the same name, for example "Test A" is in "Folder B" and also "Folder A", all subfolders and files of "Test A" in both directories should be merged.

My code so far moves only files to "Output", not in the folders and subfolders they were in before. Keep in mind this is a .bat file.

```
@echo off
for /f %%f in ('dir /b /ad') do (
  for /d %%g in ("%%f\*") do (
    if not %%g==Output xcopy "%%g" Output /e /y
  )
)
```

Comment: Edit your question and give us a better example of what the task is.  It's not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Would this be easier

```
      xcopy "c:\somefolder\*.*" "C:\somefolder\output" /exclude:"c:\someotherfolder\exclude.txt" /e /c /i /f /h /r /y /l
```

`c:\someotherfolder\exclude.txt` is a text file with the word `C:\somefolder\output` in it.

Xcopy is a compatability program and has been replaced with robocopy. But xcopy is simplier.

Type

```
xcopy /?
```

and

```
Robocopy /?
```